# Domains implicit representation

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I want to know how can we characterize the open sets $\omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ (with the usual topology) that can be represented implicitly by:

$$\omega=\{\varphi(x)\ \mid\ x\in\overline{\Omega},\ \varphi(x)<0\}$$

and

$$\partial\omega=\{\varphi(x)\ \mid\ x\in\overline{\Omega},\ \varphi(x)=0\}$$

where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ is an open set and $\varphi:\overline{\Omega}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$  are free to choose.

Is it true that all open sets from $\mathbb{R}^N$ can be written in that manner? Or what class of them can be written in that way?